# how to dynamically populate datasets using chart.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, chart.js

I am using a bar chart js for the first time that i want to populate from an array data.
this is my array

```
this.feedBackChart=[{name:"test1",id:"1",score:"5"}
{name:"test1",id:"1",score:"7"}
{name:"test2",id:2,score:"4"}]
```

i would like to populate two datasets dynamically one for test1 and one for test 2. and then add the scores for test1 which will be 12 and test2 will be 4.

this is what i tried but nothing gets shown on the page with no errors as well

```
async chart() {
        
        var barChartData = {
            datasets: []
        };
        this.feedbackChart = [];
        this.feedback.map(item => {
            let m = this.feedbackResult.find(x => x.id == item.Id);

            this.feedbackChart.push({
                ["name"]: m.metricName,
                ["id"]:item.id,
                ["score"]: item.score // im not sure how to sum up the scores here

            });
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < this.feedbackChart.length; i++) {
            barChartData.datasets.push({
                label: this.feedbackChart.map(x=> x.name),
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data:this.feedbackChart.map(x=> x.score),
            });
        }
        this.data = {
            labels: moment.months(),
            datasets: barChartData
                
            
        };

        this.config = {
            type: 'bar',
            data: this.data,
            options: {}
        };
        this.mychart = new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart") as HTMLCanvasElement, this.config);
    }
```

if i manually load the data as follows for testing purposes it works.but i cant do it this way cause the length of my array will always change

```
this.data = {
            labels: moment.months(),
            
            datasets: [{
            label: 'test1',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [12],
            },
            {
            label: 'test2',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            data: [4],
            }
]
            
        };
```

Comment: Based on the code you posted, you are setting `this.data.datasets` to `barChartData` instead of `barChartData.datasets`. That could be the reason behind nothing showing up as you expect.

Comment: urg you are right! i completely didn't notice that